# Android Edit Call Log

Tags: android, database, call, calllog

I was wondering if there was a way to modify the call log? I would like to edit date on the call.

If for example I received a call today I would like to edit the log and change the date to yesterday.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a really weird thing to do, but...

The provider for call log data ([CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html)) only publicly documents methods to query the data, not modify it. You could go into the Android source to see if there is an undocumented method.

Comment: instead of modifying a call log is there were of inserting a new one progamatically?

Comment: @MarkManickaraj maybe: [CallLog.addCall()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/provider/CallLog.java#CallLog.Calls.addCall%28com.android.internal.telephony.CallerInfo%2Candroid.content.Context%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%2Clong%2Cint%29) but you need reflection to access that.

Comment: great idea (although probably not recommended in practice). Thx.