# How can I write/edit the call log with flutter?

Tags: flutter, calllog

I've come across apps such as [Call Log Editor and Backup](https://apkpure.net/call-log-editor-and-backup/com.logger.welog/download) that can modify call records. I'm interested in creating something similar using Flutter. Despite Google Play Store's restrictions on apps that modify the call log, these apps still function on the latest Android devices.

I've done thorough online searches, but regrettably, I haven't found a solution that fits my needs. While I stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624406/android-edit-call-log) on Stack Overflow, it pertains to Android and not Flutter.